# How to show maximum value for multiple same dates within multiple date ranges in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have multiple measurements of Heart Rate within a week range. Total date range is 7 days and within each day there are multiple measurements.
I need a formula to extract Maximum value for each date.

I tried many formula combinations but Im just unable to do it.

See the screenshot below.

[image: Excel screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You might start using the `=MAXIFS()` worksheet function, like this:

```
=MAXIFS(B$1:B$14,A$1:A$14,F2)
```

In my screenshot, this is what it means:

- Take the maximum of the values in column "B" (from 1 to 14)
- The criteria that will be filtered on are the values in column "A" (also from 1 to 14)
- For this particular cell, you use the value of "F2" as a criterion.

Screenshot:

[image]

You can use `=MINIFS()` and `=AVERAGEIFS()` for the other columns.

**Edit about the `=UNIQUE()` function:**
Using the `=UNIQUE(A$2:A$70)` function, you can create the list in your "E" column automatically, did you know that? (This function only exists on the latest Excel versions, however)

Comment: Im not sure what Im missing but to me it seems lik Im using old version of Excel. When I apply your formula I get #NAME error saying "Formula contains unrecognized text"

Comment: @Wed: it might be translated: here a list of all possible translations: https://en.excel-translator.de/maxifs/

Comment: it is not about translation. I just have old Excel version that doesnt support MAXIFS function.